# Reading data from websites using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I found a bit of code by BalusC which was edited by another user: Pisek, and was wondering how to read data from another website.

I understand how to find the new class name to read different parts of data but I'm not sure how to read the quantity of the product.

Here's my code so far:

```
package internalAssessment;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class practiceArea {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

      String url = "https://www.tesco.com/groceries/product/details/?id=265485175";
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

        String price = document.select(".linePrice").text();
        System.out.println("Price: " + price);

        String quantity = document.select("").text();
        System.out.println("Quantity: " + quantity);

    }   
}
```

Comment: The quantity will always be one I assume, because this will be a new call to the webpage

Comment: Yes, as @azro said the quantity is probably always going to be 1. In general, since the id in this case (qty-265485175-1) is dynamic, you should be able to either derive the id from other field that you already know (example - product id - 265485175) or you should navigate to the desired element from a static element. Example -  document.select('.addToBasket').child(2) - would give you the quantity element.

Comment: Sorry, I think I explained my question wrong, reading the quantity of the product, as in the case of the maple syrup: 180ml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you get the price is by using the `class` :

```
String price = document.select(".linePrice").text();
```

You can also get the quantity with its `class` (or by its `id`):

```
document.select(".quantity").attr("value");          // by class
document.select("#qty-265485175-1").attr("value");   // by id
```

The thing which differ is get the number, here it is a `value` attribute so you'll use : `.attr("value");`

---

As I said in comment : this launches a nex connection to the website, so there is reason that the value you'll get will not be `1`

Comment: Sorry, I think I explained my question wrong, reading the quantity of the product, as in the case of the maple syrup: 180ml